Godot: How can I reset a scene after using queue_free()?
I have a ball (CharacterBody2D) that when it collides with an Area2D, it gets destroyed via queue_free()
extends CharacterBody2D

func _on_bottom_wall_body_entered(body):
    queue_free()

I also have a main Node scene which sets the balls X/Y position upon _ready.
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    ball_position()

func ball_position():
    $Ball.position.x = 575
    $Ball.position.y = 450

What I'm trying to do is make the ball reset back to that position after it's destroyed inside the Area2D. The reason it's being destroyed is because the Area2D is a BottomWall and if the ball touches it, the player loses a life. I wrote this script to recreate the ball.
var add_ball = preload("res://scenes/ball.tscn").instantiate()

func recreate():
    var new_ball = add_ball
    add_child(new_ball)

but it didn't work and kept giving me errors that I had to check for infinite recursion in my script. I'm wondering if there is a proper way to "reset" the (Ball) scene after destroying it.

I assume you added the last code to your ball script. This will not work, because every instance of your ball will create a new ball scene, which in return create a new ball scene... you get the drill.
If you queue_free an object, you delete the complete instance. So everytime you queue_free a ball its gone and you need to create a new instance of the scene.
Since your root node already sets the position of the ball, you could move the ball handling completely to this node.
So your Main Node could look like this:
extends Node2D
var ball_scene = preload("res://scenes/ball.tscn") #preload the ball here, so you can create instances of it later
var current_ball

func _on_bottom_wall_body_entered(body): #move the connected signal to your main node instead of the ball
    reset_ball() #may want to check if the body is the ball

func _ready():
    current_ball = $ball # using the already initiated ball from your scene as first ball
    ball_position()

func reset_ball():
    if current_ball:
        current_ball.queue_free()
    current_ball = ball_scene.instantiate()
    ball_position()
    add_child(current_ball)

func ball_position():
    current_ball.position.x = 575
    current_ball.position.y = 450

For cleaner code it may be a good idea to put all this in it's own script/node to not get it mixed with other functionalities. The ball handler can also be extended to only reset the game, if there are no balls left in the game (in case you plan to spawn more balls)

I have been studying this code for the past day and for some reason the ball won't create a new instance after after it collides with the Area2D and queue_free runs. The body of ball shows the same id as the first ball, but when reset_ball() is triggered, a new ball id is shown under print, it just doesn't show on screen or anything.

Sorry this happens, if you just write down code and don't test it before posting. Ofcourse you have to add the initiated ball to the scene. I added add_child(current_ball) at the end of the reset_ball function. Now it will show the ball in the level
